# error from apps in heroku: "require(vendor\autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, github, heroku

i made a php apps that uses phpmailer to send email from html form. this worked great on localhost (using MAMP), so i decided to upload them to github to then deploy them on heroku (i choose "github" on my heroku deplyment method). i upload pretty much everything except for the vendor folder that contains "autoload.php" file, because from browsing questions in this forum, it is not advised and not recommended, and that supposedly heroku will create those files anyway after detecting phpmailer from the composer.json file. so after i upload all of them on github and deploy the page on heroku, my pages works normal, except that the mailer function no longer works, and show this error:

> Warning: require(vendor\autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/email.php on line 11

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'vendor\autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /app/email.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /app/email.php on line 11

i tried to check the build log in heroku, but there's no error in there, altough it does have some notices (not sure if this is relevant, but i'll put it here just in case). here's my log output:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/php
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Preparing platform package installation...
       NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.json; requirements
       from dependencies in composer.lock will be used for selection
-----> Installing platform packages...
       - apache (2.4.54)
       - php (8.1.11)
       - composer (2.4.2)
       - nginx (1.22.0)
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 2.4.2 2022-09-14 16:11:15
       Installing dependencies from lock file
       Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
       Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
         - Installing phpmailer/phpmailer (v6.6.5): Extracting archive
       Generating optimized autoload files
       1 package you are using is looking for funding.
       Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
-----> Preparing runtime environment...
       NOTICE: No Procfile, using 'web: heroku-php-apache2'.
-----> Checking for additional extensions to install...
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 17.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v9
       https://ezrawibowo.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
Starting November 28th, 2022, free Heroku Dynos, free Heroku Postgres, and free Heroku Data for Redis® will no longer be available.
If you have apps using any of these resources, you must upgrade to paid plans by this date to ensure your apps continue to run and to retain your data. For students, we will announce a new program by the end of September. Learn more at https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter
```

and here's my composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.6"
    }
}
```

there might be something obvious i'm missing, because admittedly this is the first time i'm using heroku, but i've tried to search for it on heroku apps and googling my problem, and don't seem to find the specific solution for this case. any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Alright, sorry. I'll update the question later when i'm on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

**update**

i found the solution. by editing this line from my email.php:

```
require 'vendor\autoload.php';
```

to this:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

it solves the problem. my emailing function now works fine.